# What does "descunchifle" mean?

Tags: definiciones, hispanoamérica, colombia

What does the word

> descunchifle

mean?

Comment: Do you have a sentence it was used in?  The closest I can find to it is the verb desconchinflar, which means deteriorate.

Comment: Are you sure that's the word?  Google has absolutely no record of it whatsoever nor any possible suggestions, even for the unsuffixed form "cunchifle".  "Chifle" exists, but given its varied meanings from whistle to plaintain chips to powder horns for guns, it's hard to tell.  Maybe it's based on conchifero?  Can you give any context?

Comment: @TravisPessetto un amigo me contó de una ronda infantil: **"Tengo manita, y no tengo manita, porque la tengo desconchinfladita"**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [**desconchinflar**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=desconchinflar)
>
> 1. tr. Cuba, El Salv. y Méx. deteriorar (‖ estropear). U. t. c. prnl.

"Está **desconchinflado**" / It's broken.

*Desconchinfle* sería el subjuntiivo en primera persona.

Comment: ¿Pero se usa en Colombia?

Comment: Aparentemente no, ahí dice Cuba, El Salvador y México pero es posible que sí te entiendan (Conjetura mía) porque dicen mucho esa palabra en el Chavo del Ocho una serie bastante popular en toda hiapanoamérica e incluso en Brasil.

Comment: +1 por referencia a la definición de RAE de _desconchiflar_. Veo que _escachifollar_ tambien esta admitida :)

Comment: En Cuba se usa desconchinflado para decir que algo está desbaratado/roto de una manera jocosa , por ejemplo un carro roto, `ese carro esta todo desconchinflado`

Comment: @Jaime esa serie también fue popular en España, al menos para mi generación

Comment: Según el [DAMER](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=desconchinflar) se usa también en Mx, Gu, ES, Pa, Cu, PR; Pe (y CR con distinto significado).

Comment: Si. También se usa desc**o**nchi**n**fle en Colombia pero no desc**u**nchifle